# Posting to website using curl

Tags: php, url, post, curl

This may be another dumb question but anyway. I am trying to post into a search box of the University online public access catalogue and here is what I came up with:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');
$today = date('m-d-Y');
echo $today;

$keyWord=database;
$urltopost = "http://opac.usls.edu.ph/TLCScripts/interpac.dll?SearchForm?   Directions=1&Config=pac&Branch=0";
$datatopost = array ('SearchData' => "c++");

$ch = curl_init ($urltopost);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $datatopost);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$returndata = curl_exec ($ch);
echo $returndata;

?>
```

I get this:
09-19-2013
Configuration has been deleted.

I really need help. What did I do wrong?
Thanks in advance good people of this world.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at how a search is done [in that site](http://opac.usls.edu.ph/), you can see that your post url should be

`http://opac.usls.edu.ph/TLCScripts/interpac.dll?Search`

and data should be something like

`FormId=0&Config=pac&LimitsId=0&StartIndex=0&SearchField=7&SearchType=1&ItemsPerPage=10&SearchData=yoursearchtermhere`

Since in your example you're not posting the "config" parameter in post data, you get the error message you specified.